# How to resolve image attachment display issue in skype bot?

Tags: c#, botframework, skype

I am using bot framework (C# SDK) for my bot in skype. It works fine in the emulator but when i run it on the skype, it does not display image attachemnts.
I have checked documentation but i couldn't find any solution. I am not sure if it is the problem on my end or in the skype. 
Note: I am using skype for windows 10 and skype for android on my cell phone (does not work in either of these)

Here is http response for attachement in emulator

[image: emulator image]

Here is the image in skype

[image: skype image]

Here is the method that generates attachement

```
public Attachment ChartCard(StandardInfoData[] data)
{
    if (data != null && data.Length != 0)
    {
        string chartUrl = data[0]?.report?.url;

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.ContentUrl = chartUrl;
        attachment.ContentType = "image/png";
        attachment.Name = "Chart Report";

        return attachment;
    }
    else
    {
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.Content = "No Chart Report Found";
        return attachment;
    }      
}
```

Here is the code that calls this method. I am getting this image from our server "Human Collaborator" and using sockets to communicate with it.
For sockets i am using "websocket-sharp" library

```
private async Task StandardInfoFormComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<StandardInfoForm> result)
    {
        try
        {
            var form = await result;
            eventOccured = false;
            SocketStream.ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var json = e.Data;
                    StandardInfoJson response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StandardInfoJson>(json);
                    var data = response.data;
                    if (data[0].result.ToLower() == "ok")
                    {
                        // For chart reports                            
                        var chartAttachment = card.ChartCard(data);
                        replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(chartAttachment);

                        context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
                    }
                    if (data[0].result.ToLower() == "error")
                    {
                        var replyToConversation = context.MakeMessage();
                        var message = data[0]?.message;
                        replyToConversation.Text = message;
                        context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
                    }
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                }

                eventOccured = true;
            };

            //builds the botRequest part of json string
            Utilities.StringBuilder.JsonStringBuilder(context, result);
            // Instantiate JSONDataObjects class
            JSONDataObjects jdo = new JSONDataObjects();
            //Create JSON string
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jdo, Formatting.Indented);
            Debug.WriteLine("USER: \n" + output);
            //Sending the Json object to Human-Collaborator
            SocketStream.ws.Send(output);
            await context.PostAsync("Generating response.....Please Be Patient.....");
            Thread.Sleep(8000);
            if (!eventOccured)
                await context.PostAsync("Server is busy ... Please try again later");

            context.Done(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string reply;
            if (e.InnerException == null)
            {
                reply = $"You quit --maybe you can finish next time!";
            }
            else
            {
                reply = "Sorry, I've had a short circuit.  Please try again.";
            }
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
    }
```

Please help me what i am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Please share the code about how you generate the image attachment in order for us to be able to reproduce, thanks

Comment: @NicolasR I have update the question with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have all the code to replay your case but I see one important thing:

```
else
{
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.Content = "No Chart Report Found";
    return attachment;
}
```

Here you should not create an attachment as you have nothing to attach. This will throw an error because the `ContentType` is missing.

Can you modify the code that is calling your `ChartCard`: it should not call it when its parameter (your `StandardInfoData[]`) is empty.

I am not able to test more with the code you provided, but you should also check if your data in the Socket call is okay when calling from Skype (like by outputting the value or any other way), it will help in your investigation

**EDIT:** after a lot of comments on this answer, looks like the problem comes from the fact that the image is not reachable from Skype (located on a server inside user's network)

Comment: it did not help
Actually, it works fine in emulator but not in skype. If it were attachement problem it should not work in emulator as well

Comment: Did you tried the solution? It's not because the emulator is permissive that Skype will also be. I tested sending a content like you did and got the "ContentType is missing." error

Comment: Yes, i tried the solution you told me. I think issue is with the image url. Because when i tried some other url link it works but when i try to display report image url which is cached on the server does not work.
Do you think it is a valid url for skype
**http://<server ip address>:8080/human-collaborator/sessionUser/0d36b8eb-1d15-43f8-9b40-bce23b43f501/chartReport?reportId=4e2ec095-170e-4042-b030-27713b5d6c8d&format=img&type=pie**

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Don't know your server restrictions for example. but that may be an important issue yes

Comment: This link works fine in the browser though, and displays image with resolution of 1024x768.

Comment: yes but your browser calls the server directly (and maybe you are on the same network, or you have special rights...), with the botframework & Skype channel it's called from Azure / other location

Comment: yea, I am on the same network and i can not access the server outside the network. and using bot on skype through ngrok tunnel

Comment: If your server is not accessible from outside, I think you got located your problem! By the way, did you log your exceptions?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help. No i haven't logged yet, what is the best way to log?

Comment: one easy way is to use Application Insights for your project, you will get all your exceptions easily browsable from Azure Portal

Comment: Actually, I am running my bot on windows server 2012r2

Comment: So you're free to use the best logging tool you may know (I don't give any solution as it would be only primarily opinion-based)